# how to disable or hide certain button in show print preview?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, devexpress

how to disable or hide certain button when i call show print preview ?
i want to hide or disable emailto, or open, or save (any button) in print preview 
[image: print preview]

i call the print preview like

```
       private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        gridView1.ShowPrintPreview();
    }
```

is there any code to hide or disable it? or should i add a controller for the print itself ?
iam using devexpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by customizing the print settings of the GridView. To do this [BaseView.PrintInitialize](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_PrintInitializetopic.aspx) event is handled and there you are able to get the PrintingSystem associated with the gridview.

```
private void btnPrintPreview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Check whether the GridControl can be previewed.
    if (!gridControl1.IsPrintingAvailable)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The 'DevExpress.XtraPrinting' library is not found", "Error");
        return;
    }
   

    // Open the Preview window.
    gridControl1.ShowPrintPreview();
}       

private void gridView1_PrintInitialize(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.PrintInitializeEventArgs e)
{
    PrintingSystemBase pb = e.PrintingSystem as PrintingSystemBase;            
    pb.SetCommandVisibility(PrintingSystemCommand.SendPdf, CommandVisibility.None);
    pb.SetCommandVisibility(PrintingSystemCommand.SendTxt, CommandVisibility.None);
    pb.SetCommandVisibility(PrintingSystemCommand.SendRtf, CommandVisibility.None);
    pb.SetCommandVisibility(PrintingSystemCommand.SendXls, CommandVisibility.None);
    pb.SetCommandVisibility(PrintingSystemCommand.SendMht, CommandVisibility.None);
    pb.SetCommandVisibility(PrintingSystemCommand.SendXlsx, CommandVisibility.None);
    pb.SetCommandVisibility(PrintingSystemCommand.SendCsv, CommandVisibility.None);
    pb.SetCommandVisibility(PrintingSystemCommand.SendGraphic, CommandVisibility.None);
}
```

After disabling these command "SendTo" button get disabled.

**Refer these:**
[How to: Customize Print Settings When Printing GridControl](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument11543)
[Hide the tools in the print preview ribbon control](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q254334)
[How to hide toolbar buttons in the Print Preview](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A1639)
[Disable or Remove a Button from Ribbon Preview Control](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q536635)

Hope this help..

Comment: well, it works perfectly, thanks.
well itried this also `private void button16_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             PrintableComponentLink link = new PrintableComponentLink(printingSystem1);
            printingSystem1.SetCommandVisibility(PrintingSystemCommand.ClosePreview, CommandVisibility.None);
            // link.Component = gridControl1;
             link.CreateDocument();

             prnt frm = new prnt();
              frm.printControl1.PrintingSystem = printingSystem1;
             frm.Show();` it also work, but kinda complicated, prefer your more

Comment: need another form also some component. +3 if i could :D

Answer (score 0):

Will [this](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument2568) (or version with "Ribbon") suit your needs? I think you will need to do it in different way than calling:

```
gridView1.ShowPrintPreview();
```

Try with setting Document Source of DocumentViewer like is shown [here](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument2668). Hope it will work with grid's data.

Comment: well, iam also "TRY" to learn it. but i am curios if there's an easy way to hide or disable it. :D

Comment: because need a seperate form, 1 for gridview and 1 for the document viewer. and still havent try to link it. kinda hard